# PyYAML : Control ordering of items called by yaml.load()

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have a yaml setting file which creates some records in db:

```
setting1:
  name: [item,item]
  name1: text
anothersetting2:
  name: [item,item]
  sub_setting:
      name :[item,item]
```

when i update this file with *setting3* and regenerate records in db by:

```
import yaml
fh = open('setting.txt', 'r')
setting_list = yaml.load(fh)
for i in setting_list:
    add_to_db[i]
```

it's vital that the order of them settings (id numbers in db) stay the same each time as im addig them to the db... and setting3 just gets appended to the yaml.load()'s end so that its id doesn't confuse any records which are already in the db ... 
At the moment each time i add another setting and call yaml.load() records get loaded in different order which results in different ids. I would welcome any ideas ;)

**EDIT:**
I've followed *abarnert* tips and took this gist https://gist.github.com/844388

Works as expected thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The YAML spec clearly says that the key order within a mapping is a "representation detail" that cannot be relied on. So your settings file is already invalid if it's relying on the mapping, and you'd be much better off using valid YAML, if at all possible.

Of course YAML is extensible, and there's nothing stopping you from adding an "ordered mapping" type to your settings files. For example:

```
!omap setting1:
  name: [item,item]
  name1: text
!omap anothersetting2:
  name: [item,item]
  !omap sub_setting:
      name :[item,item]
```

You didn't mention which `yaml` module you're using. There is no such module in the standard library, and there are at least two packages just on PyPI that provide modules with that name. However, I'm going to guess it's PyYAML, because as far as I know that's the most popular.

The extension described above is easy to parse with PyYAML. See http://pyyaml.org/ticket/29:

```
def omap_constructor(loader, node):
    return loader.construct_pairs(node)
yaml.add_constructor(u'!omap', omap_constructor)
```

Now, instead of:

```
{'anothersetting2': {'name': ['item', 'item'],
  'sub_setting': 'name :[item,item]'},
 'setting1': {'name': ['item', 'item'], 'name1': 'text'}}
```

You'll get this:

```
(('anothersetting2', (('name', ['item', 'item']),
  ('sub_setting', ('name, [item,item]'),))),
 ('setting1', (('name', ['item', 'item']), ('name1', 'text'))))
```

Of course this gives you a `tuple` of key-value `tuple`s, but you can easily write a construct_ordereddict and get an `OrderedDict` instead. You can also write a representer that stores `OrdereredDict` objects as `!omap`s, if you need to output as well as input.

If you really want to hook PyYAML to make it use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict` for default mappings, it's pretty easy to do if you're already working directly on parser objects, but more difficult if you want to stick with the high-level convenience methods. Fortunately, the above-linked ticket has an implementation you can use. Just remember that you're not using real YAML anymore, but a variant, so any other software that deals with your files can, and likely will, break.

Answer (score 22):

My project [`oyaml`](https://github.com/wimglenn/oyaml) is a drop-in replacement for PyYAML, which will load maps into `collections.OrderedDict` instead of regular dicts.  Just pip install it and use as normal - works on both Python 3 and Python 2.

Demo with your example:

```
>>> import oyaml as yaml  # pip install oyaml
>>> yaml.load('''setting1:
...   name: [item,item]
...   name1: text
... anothersetting2:
...   name: [item,item]
...   sub_setting:
...       name :[item,item]''')
OrderedDict([('setting1',
              OrderedDict([('name', ['item', 'item']), ('name1', 'text')])),
             ('anothersetting2',
              OrderedDict([('name', ['item', 'item']),
                           ('sub_setting', 'name :[item,item]')]))])
```

Note that if the stdlib dict is order preserving (Python >= 3.7, CPython >= 3.6) then `oyaml` will use an ordinary dict.

Comment: Is that project still active and compatible with Python 3.8+?

Comment: @quassy Yes and yes

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very useful!

Answer (score 5):

You can now use **ruaml.yaml** for this.

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml:

> ruamel.yaml is a YAML parser/emitter that supports roundtrip
>   preservation of comments, seq/map flow style, and map key order

Comment: Wait, but I tried it and it returns a regular dict. Dumping it gave the keys in the wrong order. Could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: You should pass `Loader = ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader` to the `load` method in order to preserve the order.

Answer (score 0):

For a given single item that is known to be an ordered dictionary just make the items of a list and used collections.OrderedDict:

```
setting1:
  - name: [item,item]
  - name1: text
anothersetting2:
  - name: [item,item]
  - sub_setting:
      name :[item,item]

import collections
import yaml
fh = open('setting.txt', 'r')
setting_list = yaml.load(fh)

setting1 = collections.OrderedDict(list(x.items())[0] for x in setting_list['setting1'])
```

Answer (score -2):

Last I heard, PyYAML did not support this, though it would probably be easy to modify it to accept a dictionary or dictionary-like object as a starting point.

Comment: This wouldn't really work. First, YAML documents don't have to be dictionaries. Second, if you start with, say, an `OrderedDict`, all of the sub-dictionaries will still be `dict`. So what you really need is to modify it to accept a different constructor to use in place of `dict` (and, ideally, one for each constructor it uses, although the others won't be useful as often).