# How to print the first key by searching from nested yaml using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, yaml

I have below nested yaml file, I want extract only `NN41_R11`.

```
devices:
  NN41_R11:
    connections:
      defaults:
        a:
          ip: 
          port: 
          protocol: telnet
        class: 
    type: IOS
testbed:
  name:
```

I am new to yaml parsing using python, below is the code which i tried to pseudo code, but its printing the entire yaml file.

```
import yaml
stream = open('/tmp/testbed1.yaml','r')
data = yaml.load(stream)
print data.get('devices')
```

Comment: `but its printing the entire yaml file.` - It prints a *subtree* corresponded to "devices" node. If you want to get the first key of that subtree, use `list(subtree.keys())[0]` or any other receipt from that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362391/how-to-find-first-key-in-a-dictionary. Note, that YAML standard doesn't define **order** of the keys, so the first key extracted from subtree needn't to be the first key in the yaml file. However, there are some ways for remain that order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297744/pyyaml-control-ordering-of-items-called-by-yaml-load

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load the yaml file into a python nested dictionary object (key/value pairs). After this you're able to access the values of the dictionary with the dict.get('key') method.

```
# Read yaml file into nested dictionary
import yaml
fileName = '/tmp/testbed1.yaml'
with open(fileName, 'r') as yamlFile:
    data = yaml.load(yamlFile)

# Get target value
target = data.get('devices').get('NN41_R11')

# Pretty print nested dictionary (or simply print)
__import__('pprint').pprint(target)
```

Comment: your answer could be better if you add some explanation. In this way you grant your answer to be useful to all levels of knowledgement

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with below code.

```
import yaml with open("sample.yaml") as stream:
     my_dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)
     print (my_dict['devices']['NN41_R11'])
     print (my_dict.get('devices').get('NN41_R11'))
     #both the lines with give the same result you can use any
```

Similarly while iterating the keys you can get into another nested field and get the value.
[image]